# How to customize displayed task fields in task dashboard?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, spring-surf

When user login to alfresco he see task dashboard which displays the following task fields as a default.

- description (or task message)
- task name
- task status

Is there a way to add/remove fields for some users or for default task dashboard?

Comment: Yes, it is possible and you need customise/ extend the My tasks dashlet. You can add the uses into certain alfresco groups and you can control number of fields to be displayed in the my task dashlet.

Comment: Did you mean that I have to modify [share/share/src/main/webapp/components/dashlets/my-tasks.js](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/webapp/components/dashlets/my-tasks.js) with code for finding a group for assigned user and provide/render new html markup for that group?

Comment: Yes, you're correct and this will be easier.  Even you can group permission to control the behaviour of dashlet and let me find out the correct example and will come back to you. !